# creating a simple html page in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following the ruby tutorial I am trying to create a simple html page.
I will need a controller, i think for some presentation manipoulation but not DB.
I thought that I would create a model, controller and view but then I see that

```
rails generate model mainMenu freeData1:string freeData2:string
```

creates the db script.
In order to achieve a simple managed html page that would not require db, what should I create ?
controler only? what is the best practice?

what methods should I put in it for it to be displayed?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll just want a controller for the pages which will also create a views folder for your new controller that you can put HTML/ERB/whatever files in.

Since youre not working with the db, you can probably skip the need of a model.